# JMeter add specified path to embedded resource request

Tags: jmeter

Making a HTTP request in JMeter with Retrieve All Embedded Resources enabled and it is making the the page request just fine, but when it is making the requests for the embedded images, it is appending the specified path to the page in front of the full path returned for the image.

For example:

Server name = example.com

Path = folder/pageName

When it makes the requests for embedded images it is making the following request:

GET https://example.com/folder/pageName/%5C%22FullImagePath

with FullImagePath = https://example.com/files/imageName

Is there anyway to prevent the Path from being appended to the front of FullImagePath in these requests?

Answer (score 0):

I can see 2 possible reasons for this behavior:

1. A bug in your application, i.e. it refers the image in an incorrect way therefore it could not be loaded. Double check the page loading process using your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) and look into "Console" tab for possible errors and "Network" tab for `404` [HTTP Status Codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status). If browser behaves the same way as JMeter does - report the issue to your application developers.
2. A bug in JMeter. It might be the case JMeter fails to properly extract resource from the page. In this case it's better to raise an issue in [JMeter Bugzilla](https://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html). However prior to doing this I would recommend [increasing JMeter log level verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) for embedded resources downloader and check for suspicious entries in the *jmeter.log* file. You can do this by adding the next lines to *log4j2.xml* file:

   ```
   <Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser" level="debug" />
   <Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.ResourcesDownloader" level="debug" />
   ```

   most probably you will be asked for the logs by JMeter developers. You can also update your question with the log file, there is a chance that StackOverflow community will be able to come up with a suggestion or a solution. Also if your application is available to public and doesn't require login you could also post the URL to the problematic page

Comment: Thanks i'll look into that.